# TinyMCE removes assigned id='name' attribute of input

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I have recently upgraded TinyMCE from 5.7.0 to 5.10.9 and I have just realized that new version removes assigned id="name" attribute on input:

Should be like this:

`<label for="name">Your name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" tabindex="1" />`

After TinyMCE removes it:

`<label for="name">Your name:</label> <input type="text" tabindex="1" />`

You can see id="name" is missing.

Why is this happening and how to avoid this? I have also found some info that some similar bug was fixed in 5.10.6:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes5106/#thenameandidattributesofsomeelementswereincorrectlyremovedduringserialization

Comment: I have just realized that name is not the only keyword that gets removed. TinyMCE 5.10.9. also removed id='title' or id='style' or id='id'. It looks like TinyMCE does not allow keywords in id attribute that has some meaning as general attribute names of input control (input style='', input name='' input title='', ...). I have also tried to upgrade TinyMCE to latest version 7.0.0 and it works the same - it keeps removing attribute id completely if there is some keyword TinyMCE does not like inside.